# Same batch code runs successfully in 2nd attempt, why fails in 1st attempt

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
Call :YesNoBox "Press yes or no"

if "%YesNo%"=="6" (

set backupdir=D:\BackupEmail\
cd /d %backupdir%

set folder=%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%

mkdir %folder%

echo %folder% created

cd /d %folder%

mkdir Thunderbird

cd Thunderbird

set backupcmd=xcopy /s/h/i/c/k/e/r/y

echo ### Backing Up ... 

%backupcmd% "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\*" "%backupdir%\%folder%\Thunderbird\"

echo Backup Completed!

echo "Deleting Temp files".
del /s /f /q  \Windows\Temp\*.*

cmd /k 
)
exit

:: Design for pop up window
exit /b
:YesNoBox
REM returns 6 = Yes, 7 = No. Type=4 = Yes/No
set YesNo=
set MsgType=4
set heading=%~2
set message=%~1
echo wscript.echo msgbox(WScript.Arguments(0),%MsgType%,WScript.Arguments(1)) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"') do set YesNo=%%a
exit /b

:MessageBox
set heading=%~2
set message=%~1
echo msgbox WScript.Arguments(0),0,WScript.Arguments(1) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"
exit /b
```

---

I used notepad++ to save this code

Output received in command prompt:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
 created
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
A subdirectory or file Thunderbird already exists.

1. Here Thunderbird folder is created where the bat file exists, however it should have been created in "BackupEmail" folder in drive D.
2. When i ran it again on the same command prompt it runs successfully

Answer (score 2):

What this characteristic indicates is that on the first execution there is a  variable which is not `set` but its value is being used - normally in a `if` statement. However, executing the first time is establishing a value for the variable, so on the second run, the syntax is correct.

It is customary to include a `setlocal` command immediately after the `@echo off`. This makes sure that when the code is complete, any changes made to the environment are discarded. In this case, because you have no `setlocal` command, the variable's value is *retained* for the second run.

The problem with your code is the #1 FAQ - please search for `delayed expansion` using the `search` facility. The variable `folder` is not established when the `if "%YesNo%"=="6"` instruction is executed, hence *on the first occasion* 
`%folder%` has no value **BUT** it is *assigned* a value within the `code block` and it retains that value for the second run (since there is no `selocal` to discard it).

Comment: Thanks @Magoo. i implemented setlocal and its working now.